# Why does HTC Incredible S turn Wi-Fi on by itself?

Tags: wi-fi, htc-incredible-s

Sometime after latest official update to Android 4.0 phone began to switch Wi-Fi on by itself when being in sleep mode (or maybe at other times).

Reproduction: turn off the Wi-Fi, leave it in a Wi-Fi enabled area (there are open networks, but no which I would like to use), and next time I look at phone it shows this notification "There are open networks" and has the Wi-Fi enabled.

The reason I'd like to disable this behavior is phone likes to connect to some saved public Wi-Fi's when I'm on the move and browsing via 3G, thus disrupting the loading of pages. So I usually turn Wi-Fi on and off manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Incredible S but the steps should be similar:

```
Go to Settings->Wifi->Overflow Menu Button->Advanced->Keep Wifi on during sleep->Never.
```

Comment: It's strange. I'd like it would be off in sleep if it was off and on in sleep if it was on. How do I do that?

Comment: @Constantius You probably want "Never" then. I've updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes Wi-Fi switch off in sleep independently of it's state before sleeping.