# How to stop Foursquare from turning on Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, permissions

Some time ago I noticed Wi-Fi powers on without any action from me. There was a question already [from me](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33312/why-does-htc-incredible-s-turn-wi-fi-on-by-itself), asking why the phone would do this. I localized the issue to Foursquare app — it actually has a permission to change Wi-Fi state and seems to be using it to turn it on when it wants to use geolocation (which is, strangely, almost all the time). When I removed the Foursquare, Wi-Fi stopped to turn on by itself.

Is there any way to prevent Foursquare from enabling Wi-Fi without removing it and logging off from app (to be able to still use it)?

Comment: Just a thought: Can't you logoff from 4square when not using it? Or wouldn't that change its behaviour?

Comment: @Izzy I should rephrase the question: stop Foursquare from enabling the Wi-Fi without stopping to use the app.

Comment: I think I identified the app incorrectly — removal of Foursquare doesn't solve the problem in the end.

Comment: Just being curious: which app was it then?

Comment: Not sure, maybe WaveSecure

Comment: Thanks for the detail! Once you *are* sure, please update :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the permission to change the Wi-Fi state with something like [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite). There's also the possibility of using the method described in a similar question [on here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/revoke-app-permissions-without-root), this involves changing the .apk file and no root is needed.

There's a few caveats though:

- Biggest one is that when Foursquare tries to use the removed the permission it may well break depending on how the developers coded it.
- LBE Guard needs root, so you'll need to have a rooted phone.
- There have been suggestions [here](http://androidforums.com/esteem-all-things-root/555032-lbe-privacy-guard-possible-malware.html) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=20886092#post20886092) LBE Guard isn't all it's cracked up to be (buggy, hard to uninstall, might mine your data?) despite the high ratings in the marketplace.

Comment: n.b. I haven't actually used LBE Privacy Guard before and am just going off several descriptions I've read of its capabilities.

Comment: Maybe none of my apps requested that permission -- but AFAIK LBE can only block network *access* (like a firewall) and Geolocation *access*, but not the "network state change". Might be worth a try, though. Same goes for [PDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacy.pdroid). And manually patching an `.apk` is not a good thing in terms of breaking updates.

Comment: Ah well, Constantious let me know how it goes and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Peanut well, thanks for suggestion, but it seems I'm not ready for usage of such a controversial app as LBE (don't want to reset my phone because of bugs and so on).
Moreover, I don't have root access.

Comment: I'm not going to patch .apk too, so it seems I need to just get over it.