# Why does my device turn Wi-Fi on by itself?

Tags: wi-fi

Similar to [Why does HTC Incredible S turn Wi-Fi on by itself?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33312/15), it seems my Samsung Galaxy Victory will turn on Wi-Fi at random times. It establishes a connection if certain networks are in range (i.e. any open Wi-Fi).

I notice a Wi-Fi setting which allows this phone to keep its Wi-Fi on during sleep, but this is currently disabled.

Is there a way to prevent the device from looking for Wi-Fi networks?  If this is specific to Samsung devices, has anyone figured out how to take care of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching, it turns out this feature is provided by the Sprint network (although that doesn't rule out that other carriers/devices may provide similar functionality). The [Q&A at community.sprint.com](http://community.sprint.com/baw/message/507042) points to the Sprint Connection Optimizer, AKA the "Intelligent Mobile Network and Wi-Fi Setting." This setting **"will automatically connect you to Wi-Fi networks on your device's remembered list."**

This setting can be enabled/disabled by navigating to Settings > More settings > Mobile Networks > Sprint Connections Optimizer.